# How can i get proper test case report using XCPretty

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode-ui-testing, xcode8.2

I have 58 test cases in my app. I m generating test cases report using below Command:

xcodebuild  -workspace Demo.xcworkspace  -scheme Demo  -sdk iphonesimulator  -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6,OS=9.3'  test |xcpretty --report html --output outputfolderdestination/report.html

After using this command, I m getting the test report. when test report generates, Three options come in the report. I get 54 test cases passed and 4 cases failed. But my problem is that , I just can check the failed test cases only. I m not able to see the passed test cases of passing section in the test report.

Comment: Please give me solution as soon as possible

Comment: I am using 0.2.4 version of xcpretty and it seems fine I can display both success and failed tests. Try updating your xcpretty.

Comment: I m also using updated  0.2.6 version of XCPretty but I can not display both pass and fail test cases.

Comment: The only thing I can say try version 0.2.4 if does not work you can open an issue on github